# PHP - url question

Tags: php

How can I turn example 1 into example 2 using PHP

Example 1

```
http://www.example.com/categories/fruit/apple/green
```

Example 2

```
http://www.example.com/categories/index.php?cat=fruit&sub1=apple&sub2=green
```

Comment: Not really the job for PHP, look into [mod_rewrite](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php) or similar (depending on what http server you're running on).

Comment: @Bhanu, @Reese Moore, an example would be helpful

Comment: @HeLp what do you mean by 'turn into'? If you want to cause a redirect, yes you need to use htaccess if you need to rewrite data that you are turning into links then yes, you could do it in PHP with a regex, please clarify exactly what you want to do.

Comment: @tobyodavies, I really dont no what you mean but an example of both would help me clear up things.

Comment: What do you want to do with these urls? serve URL1 as if it were URL2, display them to people, bake them a cake? We need more details to answer the question.

Comment: serve URL1 as if it were URL2 and display them to people,

Answer (score 1):

As has been suggested, this is something to be done through HTACCESS and mod_rewrite rules. The best trick for things like this would be to have a go, share what you have managed to come up with (and the results or bugs) and people will then help you find a complete solution.

That being said, I would suggest something like the following, in a file called ".htaccess" in your webroot.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f # Means if the requested address is not a file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d # Means if the requested address is not a dir
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ index.php?cat=$1&sub1=$2&sub2=$3
```

I have not tested the above code, but it would be where I would start, and maybe mix with some independent research as required...

Some links:

- http://www.htmlist.com/how-to/a-simplemod_rewrite-tutorial/
- http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite
- http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/urlrewriting.html
- http://www.easymodrewrite.com/guide-syntax

Answer (score 0):

That's just simple string manipulation - but note that changing the request URI *within** your script won't automatically populate the relevant $_GET variables.

To change the string:

```
  <?php
  $input_url='http://www.example.com/categories/fruit/apple/green';
  $parts=parse_url($input_url);
  $embeds=explode('/',$parts['path']);
  $new_path=array_shift(embeds) . '/index.php'; // store 'categories' for later
  $count=1;
  $join=strlen($parts['qry']) ? '&' : '?';
  foreach ($embeds as $val) {
      $parts['query'].=$join . 'ub' . $count . '=' . urlencode($val);
      $join='&';
  }
  $out_url=$parts['scheme'] . '://' 
     . ($parts['username'] . $parts['password']) ? 
             $parts['username'] . ':' $parts['password'] . '@' : ''
     . $parts['host'] . '/' . $new_path
     . $parts['query']
     . '#' . $parts['fragment'];
  print $out_url;
```